# PHPExcel set multiple pages on PDF

Tags: php, pdf, phpexcel

I'm trying to get my PHPExcel code to get multiple pages on PDF from creating new "Sheets". I have this example to be helped.

```
include_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF;
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/tcpdf';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objSheetRes = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$objSheetRes->setTitle('Title');
$objPHPExcel->createSheet()->setTitle('Title 2');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'SHEET 1');


if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName,$rendererLibraryPath)) {
    die('NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
        '<br />' .
        'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure');
}

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename= "example.pdf"');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: hey! first of all thanks for the answer, and sorry for the late. so this is the problem, when i'm having this to pdf i just have only one page to print when i put more than 2 new sheets.

Comment: You'll need to print/save each worksheet individually

Comment: that's the point all i got is a simple page (the first sheet)

Comment: Use the `setSheetIndex()` method to tell the writer which worksheet to write

Comment: i've searched on google for an example on how to use it, but no luck. Can you, please give me some?

Answer (score 0):

How much of an example do you actually need?

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->setSheetIndex(1);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Will generate a report showing the second worksheet (sheets are indexed from 0)

Comment: I get that point. The only thing i don't know how to do, is to create all the pages, if i have 10 sheets i wan't to create the 10 pages in the pdf and i just getting 1 page with setSheetIndex()

Comment: Well one option would be to save each to a temp file, and then either zip those files up together and download that zip, or use a PDF "stitcher" to combine them all into a single PDF for download

Comment: i'm really new in this area, and i'm a little confused. i understand all you're saying. But the only thing i want to know is: "how i can create all the pdf pages at once?" i link you the code i'm using. thanks [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dqt)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it with this:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->writeAllSheets();  //This allow export multiple sheets
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Check this: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md#write-all-worksheets